# can an account be blocked by one highly rated user

Tags: discussion

I cannot answer any stackexchange answers as a few of my (first) posts were flagged and downgraded by a single user with loads of points. help suggests I post more useful replies to get me more points, but as no one else has read or upgraded any answers I have posted, I am -ve and cant post. is that OK for you?

Answer (score 7):

All of the helpful flags on your posts were by different users, and the amount of reputation the person flagging your post has doesn't actually affect anything. The good news is it looks like you're no longer blocked as of about an hour ago, so you should be fine as long as you post high-quality answers.